# How to style nested <div> depending on class in body-tag

Tags: html, css, angular

In my `<app-root>` I have `<app-sidebar>` in which I have a `<div class="myClass">`.
In my body tag I have class "myBodyClass" that toggles. I want to style my div depending on the class in the body-tag, what I have is somthing like this:

```
.myClass{
  background-color:red;
}
.myBodyClass > .myClass{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

tryed as well:

```
 .myBodyClass .myClass{
  background-color:yellow;
 }
```

but none of them works ,what is the correct way to achive that?

Comment: share your full HTML then

Comment: I believe the problem being faced here is to due with Angular and possibly style encapsulation. I don’t believe it’s a duplicate of any of the answers above.

Comment: @TemaniAfif at my mobile at the moment will share an example as soon I'm back at my computer (y)

Comment: I can't add answer since question is closed for now, but try that in your sidebar component  `:host-context(.myBodyClass) myClass {
  background-color:yellow;
}`

Comment: I agree with @HugoNoro this is angular specific

Comment: @TemaniAfif can you please have a second look at the question? I believe it was wrongly closed.

Comment: @HugoNoro without any more information we cannot know ... check his first edit and we have no information about the HTML ... so for me it's a specifity issue until he provide more code ... will reopen the question if it's not the case

Comment: @David You are a savior- that is correct - will accept it as an answer as soon it is avaiable , ty again(y)

Comment: @TemaniAfif fair enough. pb4now please provide additional code to clarify the issue you are facing. And ideally also please update the title of the question to make it more clear

Comment: question reopned, but add more clarification so we know it's an angular issue

Comment: @HugoNoro well in that case will have to create some simple exampe in plunkr and put link here -pls just give me an hour  or so I can seat down with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `host-context` combinator

> Sometimes it's useful to apply styles based on some condition outside of a component's view. For example, a CSS theme class could be applied to the document  element, and you want to change how your component looks based on that.

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host-context

```
:host-context(.myBodyClass) myClass {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

The other solution is to declare that rule in the global stylesheet, not in your component' css (because of the default encapsulation)